# Regex check first character

Tags: regex

I want to use a regex first character is equal 5 and other string must be number. For example 5046834578 or 5789825364. I used a pattern for to check all string is number but it is not enough to check. How can I do?

```
var pattern=[0,9];
```

Comment: That's very basic regex use, please follow a quick tutorial on regex, you'll learn much more from it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hYtLC9/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the regex you need:

```
/^5\d+$/
```

Anything in / pairs are resolve as regex.

- `^` means it must starts with the following rule.
- `5` means 5.
- `\d` means any digit.
- `+` means previous rule repeat 1 or more than 1 time.
- `$` means it must ends with the previous rule.

Here's the full code:

```
var regex = /^5\d+?$/;
var tester = '556464622';
var result = regex.test(tester); // true
```

Comment: The way you explained every single character is really applaudable. Thanks.